# React beautiful DND with typescript react-beautiful-dndUnable to find draggable with id: 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I am trying to make my list of stuff draggable, because it will be used to reorder a set of items retrieved from an API. All these items will have a prop named `number`, and with the drag and drop, I should change the order and the number in the visualization.

I followed along with some tutorials, the documentation, and many StackOverflow questions, but I have not been able to fix the problem. Each time I try to grab an element, in the console appears a warning message with the following content:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4012 
react-beautiful-dndUnable to find draggable with id: 1‍ 
This is a development-only message. It will be removed in production builds.
```

Here is the code I am working on:

Categories.tsx file with all the logic:

```
// Global imports
import {DragDropContext,Droppable, DropResult} from "react-beautiful-dnd";

// Local imports
// Context
import { menuContext } from "../menu";
// Components
import CategoryItem from "./cateogory";
// Types
import Category from "../../types/category";

function Categories(){
    const {categories, setCategories} = useContext(menuContext);
    /*functions and logic*/
    const onDragEnd = (result:DropResult) => {
        const {destination, source} = result;
        if (!destination) return;

        const items = Array.from(categories);
        const [newOrder] = items.splice(source.index, 1);
        items.splice(destination.index, 0, newOrder);

        setCategories(items);
    }

    return (
        <div className="greyBox">
            <header className="header_menu">
                <p>All your categories</p>
                <div className="searchContainer">
                    <AiOutlineSearch className="searchIcon" />
                    <input type={"text"} placeholder={"Search"} className="searchBar" value={search} 
                        onChange={(e) => handleModification(e)} />
                </div>
            </header>

            <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
                <Droppable droppableId="categories">
                    {(provided) =>
                        <div {...provided.droppableProps} 
                            ref={provided.innerRef}
                            className="categoriesContainer" >

                        {filteredCategories.map((category: Category, idx: number) => {
                            return (
                                <CategoryItem  key={category.id} idx={idx} category={category}/>
                                )
                            })}

                    </div>}
                </Droppable>
            </DragDropContext>
            <button onClick={(e) => confirmChanges(e)} className="submitBTN bottomButton">Confirm changes</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Categories;
```

Category.tsx File into I have the single Item:

```
// Global imports
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

// Local imports
// Context
import { menuContext } from "../menu";
// Types
import Category from "../../types/category";

function CategoryItem(props:{category:Category, idx:number}) {
    const {categories, setCategories} = useContext(menuContext);
    const {selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory} = useContext(menuContext);

    /*Functions and various small things*/

    let category = categories.find((category:Category) => category.id === props.category.id);   

    return (
        <Draggable key={props.category.id} draggableId={props.category.id.toString()} index={props.idx}>
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
                <div className={selectedCategory === category.id ? "category activeCategory":"category"}
                onClick={() => handleCategoryClick()} 
                style={{backgroundColor: category.isActive ? "" : "#FF7B7B"}}
                ref={provided.innerRef} 
                {...provided.draggableProps}
                {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                >
                        
                    <div className="alwaysActiveCategory" style={{alignItems: props.category.id === selectedCategory ? "center" : "normal"}}>
                        <MdOutlineDragIndicator className="dragIcon" />
                        <p style={{display: props.category.id === selectedCategory ? "none" : "block" }}>{category.name}</p>
                    </div>
        
                    <aside style={{display: selectedCategory === category.id ? "flex": "none"}}>
        
                        <form className="modifyCategory" onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} onSubmit={e => updateCategory(e)}>
                            <label htmlFor="categoryName">Category Name</label>
                            <p id="categoryProblem3">The name must be given</p>
                            <input value={name} onChange={(e) => changeName(e)} type="text" name="categoryName" id="categoryName" />    
                            <label htmlFor="categoryDescription">Category Description</label>
                            <p id="categoryProblem4">The description must be given</p>
                            <textarea value={description} onChange={(e) => changeDescription(e)} name="categoryDescription" id="categoryDescription" 
                                    style={{maxWidth: "85%"}} />
                            <button>Update Category</button>
                            <div className="manageCategory">
                                <button onClick={(e) => hideCategory(e) }> <BiHide className="hideIcon" 
                                        style={{backgroundColor: categories.find((category: Category) => category.id === props.category.id).isActive ? "#FF7B7B" : "#76CB8E"}} /> 
                                    {category.isActive ? "Hide Category" : "Show Category"}
                                </button>
                                <button onClick={(e) => deleteCategory(e)}> <BsTrash className="deleteIcon" /> Delete Category</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
        
                        
                    </aside>
                </div>
            )}
        </Draggable>
    )
}

export default CategoryItem;
```

They are pretty long, I tried to take away everything useless.

I don't know where the problem is in this script. It seems all fine to me, but there are some problems otherwise it wouldn't broke each time. If someone knows where my mistakes are, please tell me. Thank you a lot